# How to add Metaplex/Candymachine function to an existing website?

Tags: reactjs, blockchain, nft, metaplex, candy-machine

I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction. I would like to add the Metaplex/candymachine function to an existing website that was originally  built to work with metamask. Just trying to save myself from having to redo the website. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no real easy way to do this unfortunately unless you have some prior HTML/CSS/and JS knowledge.

What some people do is take the logic from the CandymachineUI which can be found here [CandyMachine.ts](https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex/blob/master/js/packages/candy-machine-ui/src/candy-machine.ts) which is a type script file and port it over to their own website. You could also attempt to remake the UI calling to these functions and data, or failing that pulling the existing Mint area out the [CandymachineUI site](https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex/tree/master/js/packages/candy-machine-ui) (built on React) and attempting to slot that into your existing site. I'd recommend if you took that approach that you swap out the MUI components for div's and your own CSS to save adding MUI to your site adding some bloat (unless your site already uses MUI then you good to go).

Bare in mind you'll also need the supporting dependecies too.

There are also other community built UI's out there but you are going to run into the same issues of porting over all the js/ts to your own site.

I always say it's generally quicker to rebuild a site around an already made mint template than it is to put the mint function into an original.

Comment: Hi Tony! thanks for your reply. I going to try this now. I totally get what your saying, this has been really helpful.